# Objective-C: Programmatically set file privileges to current user

Tags: cocoa, macos, nsfilemanager

I working on a program that manages documents. One of the things my app does, is download document from the internet and open them. This documents I download need to be opened with Read Only privileges.

So, I was wondering if there is a way of programmatically setting the privileges of a file.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In addition to `chmod` mentioned by @Vlad, you can also use the `setAttributes:ofItemAtPath:error:` method of `NSFileManager` with an attribute of `NSFileImmutable`:

```
NSDictionary* attribs = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:YES] forKey:NSFileImmutable];
[[NSFileManager defaultManager]  setAttributes: attribs ofItemAtPath:@"/path/to/file" error:nil];
```

Answer (score 1):

Sure, use [`chmod`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man2/chmod.2.html#//apple_ref/doc/man/2/chmod).